# Adding a Like Me button to my website

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I am adding this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fourdailybreaddesigns&amp;width=175&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color=blue&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=590" 
        scrolling="no" 
        frameborder="0" 
        style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:175px; height:590px;" 
        allowTransparency="true"
        >
</iframe>
```

and getting this error message:

> Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in.

Comment: You *have* to provide more information than that. What was the URL? Where is your code? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL should also contain the ID for your site, not just:

http://www.facebook.com/ourdailybreaddesigns

EDIT:

On second though, that a profile, not a site? Probably why it's not working.

Let me put it this way: You can't have a likebox because it's not possible to "like" your profile.

Answer (score 0):

THe HTML is fairly simple:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="facebook.com/CNN"        
data-width="272" data-height="500" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="true" 
data-header="false"> </div>
```

I have a similar situation of handling such feed ERROR when the URL/HREF is not right and feed is empty. e.g

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="facebook.com/CNNNNN"        
data-width="272" data-height="500" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="true" 
data-header="false"> </div>
```

How to handle the empty FB feed. I dont want this error to be displayed:

"Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in."

(No intention to hijack this thread, it actually solves the same problem at the end of the day)